# Angular ng-show and ng-change to show and hide tables depending on the user selection in <select> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, show-hide, ng-show, angularjs-ng-change

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I should've made it more clear but what I wanted also was **if I select from the "drop down 1"** other than the `null` value, my **table 2** automatically **disappears** b/c I only want to see **table 1** when I am using **drop down 1**.  Same thing for **"drop down 2"**. If I choose any non-null values from **drop down 2**, my table 1 disappears and I only see **table 2.** I also updated my Fiddle here  https://jsfiddle.net/missggnyc/4vod1L9g/7/ and the tables are hiding if the `null` values are selected from the drop down.  All I need now is how to show one or the other table depending on which drop down I am using.

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**
I am getting a bit confused about how to use `ng-show` or `ng-change` to show my two different tables depending on the user selection with two dif. drop downs.

Here's the scenario:

As long as the user doesn't select `SELECT YOUR ANSWER` with `null` value in both drop downs, I have a filter that does the string comparison and filters out by color. This is what I want to do.

User selects from "drop down 1"

- show table 1 with filtered results if the user doesn't select "SELECT YOUR ANSWER" with null value
- if the user selects "SELECT YOUR ANSWER", then no tables are displayed
- hide table 2 as long as "drop down 1" is getting selected

User selects from "drop down 2"

- show table 2 with filtered results if the user doesn't select "SELECT YOUR ANSWER" with null value
- if the user selects "SELECT YOUR ANSWER", then no tables are displayed
- hide table 2 as long as "drop down 1" is getting selected

I am confused about how to use ng-show or ng-change in my case. Any suggestions?

[See demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/missggnyc/uuw93vv2/17/)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myColors">
  <div ng-controller="cController">
    <h3>drop down 1</h3>
    <select ng-model="selectedAnswer1" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection1" ng-change=""></select>
    <pre>{{selectedAnswer1}}</pre>
       <h3>drop down 2</h3>
    <select ng-model="selectedAnswer2" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection2"></select>
    <pre>{{selectedAnswer2}}</pre>
    <hr>
    <h4>
     table 1
    </h4>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Category</td>       
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="f in fruit">
        <td>{{f.id}}</td>
        <td>{{f.f_category}}</td>        
      </tr>
    </table>

    <h4>
      table 2
    </h4>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Car</td>
      </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="c in car">        
        <td>{{c.category}}</td>        
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("myColors", []);
app.controller("cController", function($scope) {
    $scope.mySelection1 = [
    {"cat": "SELECT YOUR ANSWER", "value": null}, 
    {"cat": "YELLOW",  "value": "yellow"},
    {"cat": "ORANGE", "value": "orange"}
  ];
  $scope.mySelection2 = [
    {"cat": "SELECT YOUR ANSWER",  "value": null }, 
    {"cat": "GREEN CAR",  "value": "green"},
    {"cat": "BLUE CAR", "value": "blue"}
  ];
  $scope.fruit = [{
    "id": "red",
    "f_category": ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Pineapple"]
  }, {
    "id": "yellow",
    "f_category": ["Banana", "Pineapple"]
  }, {
    "id": "orange",
    "f_category": ["Peach", "Nectarine"]
  }];

  $scope.car = [{
    "name": "yellow",
    "category": ["SUV", "Truck"]
  }, {
    "name": "blue",
    "category":  ["Van"]
  }, {
    "name": "orange",
    "category": ["Mini-Van"]
  }];

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
as far I understood you only want show/hide the other table if the first one is select. Here is a simple solution:

```
 <div ng-app="myColors">
  <div ng-controller="cController">
    <h3>drop down 1</h3>
    <select name="select1" ng-model="selectedAnswer1" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection1" ng-change="selection1Change()"></select>
    <pre>{{selectedAnswer1}}</pre>
       <h3>drop down 2</h3>
    <select name="select2" ng-model="selectedAnswer2" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection2" ng-change="selection2Change()"></select>
    <pre>{{selectedAnswer2}}</pre>
    <hr>
    <div ng-show="selectedAnswer1 && flag1">
    <h4>
     table 1
    </h4>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Category</td>       
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="f in fruit" ng-show="selectedAnswer1.value === f.id">
        <div >
        <td >{{f.id}}</td>
        <td >{{f.f_category}}</td> 
        </div>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div  ng-show="selectedAnswer2 && flag2">
    <h4>
      table 2
    </h4>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Car</td>
      </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="c in car" ng-show="selectedAnswer2.value === c.name">        
        <td>{{c.category}}</td>        
      </tr>
    </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module("myColors", []);
app.controller("cController", function($scope) {

    $scope.mySelection1 = [
    {"cat": "SELECT YOUR ANSWER", "value": null}, 
    {"cat": "YELLOW",  "value": "yellow"},
    {"cat": "ORANGE", "value": "orange"}
  ];
  $scope.mySelection2 = [
    {"cat": "SELECT YOUR ANSWER",  "value": null }, 
    {"cat": "GREEN CAR",  "value": "green"},
    {"cat": "BLUE CAR", "value": "blue"}
  ];
  $scope.fruit = [{
    "id": "red",
    "f_category": ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Pineapple"]
  }, {
    "id": "yellow",
    "f_category": ["Banana", "Pineapple"]
  }, {
    "id": "orange",
    "f_category": ["Peach", "Nectarine"]
  }];

  $scope.car = [{
    "name": "yellow",
    "category": ["SUV", "Truck"]
  }, {
    "name": "blue",
    "category":  ["Van"]
  }, {
    "name": "orange",
    "category": ["Mini-Van"]
  }];
  $scope.selection1Change = function(){
   $scope.flag1 = true;
   $scope.flag2 = false;
  }
    $scope.selection2Change = function(){
  $scope.flag1 = false;
  $scope.flag2 = true;
  }
});
```

---

OLD: 
No need for to use ng-change, because angularjs itself it will be update the value of ng-model, so you can use ng-show with the value of ng-model, as show in the code bellow:

```
<div ng-app="myColors">
  <div ng-controller="cController">
    <h3>drop down 1</h3>
    <select ng-model="selectedAnswer1" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection1"></select>
    <pre>{{selectedAnswer1}}</pre>
       <h3>drop down 2</h3>
    <select ng-model="selectedAnswer2" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection2"></select>
    <pre>{{selectedAnswer2}}</pre>
    <hr>
    <h4>
     table 1
    </h4>
    <table ng-show="selectedAnswer1">
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Category</td>       
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="f in fruit" ng-show="selectedAnswer1.value === f.id">
        <div >
        <td >{{f.id}}</td>
        <td >{{f.f_category}}</td> 
        </div>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <h4>
      table 2
    </h4>
    <table ng-show="selectedAnswer2">
      <tr>
        <td>Car</td>
      </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="c in car" ng-show="selectedAnswer2.value === c.name">        
        <td>{{c.category}}</td>        
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... so much simpler than I expected. Just triggering with true and false combo. Thanks for the answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

`ng-show` allows you to take advantage of databinding, so you don't have to manually watch events like you would do in vanilla JS (with event handlers or onchange attribute). It's the preferred way to do things in angularJs. Use ngChange only when you have no other choice.

Also, it would probably be even better to use `ng-if` here since you would spare the cost of building the tables when not shown.

Answer (score 0):

using `ng-change` and `filter` directive you achieve the behaviour you are expecting, take a look at this snippet

```js
var app = angular.module("myColors", []);
app.controller("cController", function($scope) {
 $scope.selectedFruit = null;
 $scope.selectedCar = null;
 $scope.mySelection1 = [
    {"cat": "SELECT YOUR ANSWER", "value": null}, 
    {"cat": "YELLOW",  "value": "yellow"},
    {"cat": "ORANGE", "value": "orange"}
  ];
  $scope.mySelection2 = [
    {"cat": "SELECT YOUR ANSWER",  "value": null }, 
    {"cat": "GREEN CAR",  "value": "green"},
    {"cat": "BLUE CAR", "value": "blue"}
  ];
  $scope.fruit = [{
    "id": "red",
    "f_category": ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Pineapple"]
  }, {
    "id": "yellow",
    "f_category": ["Banana", "Pineapple"]
  }, {
    "id": "orange",
    "f_category": ["Peach", "Nectarine"]
  }];
  
  $scope.car = [{
    "name": "yellow",
    "category": ["SUV", "Truck"]
  }, {
    "name": "blue",
    "category":  ["Van"]
  }, {
    "name": "orange",
    "category": ["Mini-Van"]
  }];
 
 $scope.selectFruit = function(selectedItem){
  $scope.selectedFruit = selectedItem.value; 
 } 
 $scope.selectCar = function(selectedItem){
  $scope.selectedCar = selectedItem.value; 
 }
  
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myColors">
  <div ng-controller="cController">
    <h3>drop down 1</h3>
    <select ng-model="selectedAnswer1" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection1" ng-change="selectFruit(selectedAnswer1)"></select>
    <pre>{{selectedAnswer1}}</pre>
       <h3>drop down 2</h3>
    <select ng-model="selectedAnswer2" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection2" ng-change="selectCar(selectedAnswer2)"></select>
    <pre>{{selectedAnswer2}}</pre>
    <hr>
    <h4>
     table 1
    </h4>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Category</td>       
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="f in fruit | filter:selectedFruit">
        <td>{{f.id}}</td>
        <td>{{f.f_category}}</td>        
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <h4>
      table 2
    </h4>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Car</td>
      </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="c in car | filter:selectedCar">        
        <td>{{c.category}}</td>        
      </tr>
    </table>
    
  </div>
</div>
```